# Disable AmbientMode for WearOS Apps?

Tags: android, wear-os, samsung-galaxy

To keep a Wear OS app always visible I have been using

```
window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON)
```

Unfortunately if the watch face is accidentally covered the app still moves to Ambient Mode

Ideally I want to disable AmbientMode altogether but can see no means of achieving this.

Instead the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/views/always-on) indicates keeping the display on requires the app to monitor entry and exit of ambient mode. Once in Ambient Mode it is recommended the screen is updated less frequently using a repeating alarm. It all appears overly complex when all I want is the App to remain visible and updating at the same rate.

Hence my first thought was to implement the AmbientMode callback and if the watch tries to enter AmbientMode it is set back to Interactive Mode. Something like:

```
private class MyAmbientCallback : AmbientModeSupport.AmbientCallback() {

    override fun onEnterAmbient(ambientDetails: Bundle?) {
      // on entry to ambient mode set state back to Interactive Mode
      ambientState = AmbientState.Interactive
    }

}
```

Unfortunately this does not appear to be supported

So can anyone suggest how to disable AmbientMode or set the App back to InteractiveMode if it is (accidentally) placed into AmbientMode?

Comment: "Users simply place their palm over the watch face and the app terminates." - well, no. The watch goes into ambient mode, something [your app can support](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/views/always-on). Did you enable always on support specifically so that your app isn't terminated when the user palms the device?

Comment: So...did you enable always on mode support in your app so your app isn't terminated?

Comment: @ianhanniballake I do not want the app to terminate - The reason I did not implement a WAKE_LOCK is I don't want to handle ambient mode - I don't want the watch to ever enter ambient mode

Comment: Did you read the docs I pointed out? Your app doesn't terminate if you follow those docs.

Comment: @ianhanniballake thank you for pointing out my error - I have completely restructured the question hopefully clarifying my request. The simplest example application is a countdown timer updated every second which must never stop (only a press of the Home key will terminate the countdown early). So the display and update rate remains identical in both Ambient and Interactive Modes.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to force the device to never go into Ambient Mode as that is absolutely critical to having any reasonable battery life on a Wear OS device.

By supporting Ambient Mode, your app can continue to run and can continue to update your screen until the user chooses to interact with their watch again (i.e., raise their wrist, etc. based on the user's preferences), which would move your app back into interactive mode.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @ianhanniballake - Tried using the AlarmManager to schedule wake ups but this also prioritises battery preservation by preventing alarms more often than every 5 seconds (or for scheduled alarms >1 minute)

Comment: That's correct, the user gets to choose when to tap the screen, lift their wrist, etc. to return to interactive mode and run their battery quickly down to 0%.